# Can the filename of a video uploaded to YouTube be seen by someone other than the uploader?

Tags: youtube, privacy, youtube-studio

The filename of a video uploaded to YouTube can be seen by the uploader:

[image]

Can the filename of a video uploaded to YouTube be seen by someone other than the uploader?

Assume that the video title is different from the filename of a video uploaded to YouTube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename of a video uploaded to YouTube cannot be seen by anyone else  other than the uploader. In other words, it's some private metadata. Note that not all videos have a filename: it [depends](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172831/18147) on how the video was uploaded.