# Why do some YouTube videos have a filename while others don't?

Tags: youtube-studio

Some YouTube videos have a filename, e.g.:

[image]

and other don't:

[image]

Both others don't. Why? What decides whether a YouTube video has a filename?

Comment: Let's keep [tag:youtube] for questions about the YouTube web app. Use [tag:youtube-creator-studio] for questions about YouTube Studio. P.S. There is already a request on [meta] to rename the tag. P.S.S. There is an overlap with [video.se]. It might be worth looking at their main chatroom / per-site Meta.

Comment: @Rubén thanks this is a good idea, I forgot that the YT studio tag existed. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: @BlindSpots The filename [can't](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/165845/18147) be  be seen by anyone else other than the uploader. In other words, it's some private metadata. Therefore, I can't share an example aside from sharing a screenshot showing no filename. Shall I share a screenshot showing no filename?

Comment: @BlindSpots sure thing, added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What decides whether a YouTube video has a filename?

That depends on how the video was uploaded to YouTube:

- If one used the web app (i.e., https://www.youtube.com/) for the video upload, the YouTube video **will have** a filename, even if uploading multiple videos at once, and even if using Android when accessing the web app (i.e., upload via https://m.youtube.com/upload and not the Android YouTube application).
- If one used the YouTube Android or iOS app for the video upload, the YouTube video **will not** have a filename.

Tested with Windows 10 + Chrome, iOS 15 + iPhone 12 mini, and Android 13 + S23 Ultra.

Comment: Good detail in answer 

Comment: @BlindSpots thanks, that puzzled me for a while.