# Where can I add some private information on a video I uploaded on YouTube and publicly shared?

Tags: youtube-studio

I uploaded a video on YouTube. I shared it publicly. Where can I add on YouTube some private information on a video? E.g., is there any field in the YouTube Studio that would allow me to write down some private information about the video?

Example of use cases:

- Some videos [don't](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172831/18147) have a filename, I'd like to write down the filename somewhere in the information about the video on YouTube but keep the filename private.
- I'd like to write down the exact date, location and shooting information of the video, but I don't want to make it known publicly.

Comment: Is the filename public?